# CSS: Image and text align in wordpress post

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have little problem floating text and image in wordpress post. I want to have little space between text and picture. When I try to make it with merge or padding in css, It does nothing or text goes below pic. please help me, page url: http://uglt.org/new/?p=2224

see pic, how I want to be and how is it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNUxq.jpg

php code:

```
        <?php if($image) : ?>
        <img class="img-responsive singlepic" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/><div class="singu"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?> 

    <div class="entry-content">
```

By the way when I try to make these two class into one div It goes below too. Please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: `<img ... /> <div ...>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a padding-right to the image element.

Comment: In the <head> of your file, add the following:

Comment: <style>img.singlepic {padding-right: 10px;}</style>

Answer (score 0):

Just use the css property:

```
 margin-right:10px
```

for example, having the class:

```
 .rightSpacing {
   margin-right:10px
 }
```

then you could use

```
<img class="img-responsive singlepic rightSpacing" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/>
```

use the number of pixels you might feel necessary, 10 is just an example.